# Is $\frac{dy}{dx}$ a function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

I often  $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in differential equations written as a number, such as $\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$ but also written as a function in  $\frac{dy}{dx}(x)$ is it either a number or a function? Or does it's exact status depend on our use?

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a notation for the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$, so it is a function. In the notation $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x$ we actually mean $\frac{dy}{dx}(x) = 2x$, so $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is meant to be the function $x \mapsto 2x$.

Comment: It is not a constant (number). You can write as well $y^{'}(x)$, which is the derivative of $f(x)$. If the RHS does **not depend on $y$** then I would say it is a function. Let say $y(x)=\frac12\cdot a \cdot x^2$. Then $y(x)$ is a function for the distance at time x. Then $y^{'}(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}=a\cdot x$ is also a function, but with a different meaning. In this case the speed at time $x$.

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac {dy}{dx}$ represents the derivative of a function $y$ with respect to $x.$  Other represenations of $\displaystyle \frac {dy}{dx}$ are $f'(x)$ or $y'$.

Answer (score 1):

$2x$ can be seen as both a number, namely for $x \in \mathbb R$ the number $2x$. It can also be seen as a function, namely the map $x \mapsto 2x$.

If $x \mapsto y(x)$ is map, $y^\prime(x)= \frac{dy}{dx}$ is  also a map. So writing the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x$ is not an issue if your consider $2x$ as the map $x \mapsto 2x$.

Comment: To add another item to your list, $2x$ can also be considered a *polynomial* (i.e. an *expression* of the form $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots+a_nx^n$), distinct from a *polynomial function*, which is the mapping given by the evaluation. (The difference being more apparent when the evaluation is simpler than the expression, e.g. in fields where $2x$ always evaluates to $0$.) The point being, we can consider most mathematical objects as different, but naturally equivalent, types. Mathematical objects may wear many different hats.

Comment: But, $2x$ is a number and the function that maps $x$ to $2x$ is not denoted by $2x$ but by the arrow notation you use, so to equate a function to a number doesn't feel right.

Comment: @user1007028 This is an abuse of notation, that is often made. Here, $2x$ stands for a function.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net ah, so we slightly abuse the notation with the understanding that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is actually the function that would give the value of $2x$ at $x$ but just equate them so we don't have to think about al these parenthesis?

Comment: @user1007028 That is correct.

Comment: The bottom line with all these examples is that notation in the domain of differential is often (to use a term from computer science) "overloaded" and one need to context to disambiguate.